# Reading a .txt file using Scanner class in Java - closing it

Tags: java, swing, java.util.scanner, jtextarea, nosuchelementexception

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at main.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:43)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:39)
```

I've already tried with `scan.close();` but that did not work. All I want is to work without anything in the txt.

The Scanner it is "attached" to a `JTextArea`.

```
public Frame() throws FileNotFoundException {        
    Scanner scan = new Scanner((new File("D:/kek.txt")));
    String all = scan.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```

Comment: Use `hasNext()` to ensure there is a next token

Comment: `Scanner.next()` will throw when there are no (more) tokens available.  You must therefore either avoid invoking it under those circumstances -- by first testing with `hasNext()`, for example -- or catch and ignore that specific exception.

Comment: @GBlodgett i've tried your way and it works. But when i'm trying to put something into txt it won't read. Making it String all= scan.hasNext(); it will give me an error at that line.

Comment: Use a loop: `while(scan.hasNext()) { //Read in info}`

Comment: @GBlodgett on the specific line , "String  all=scan.hasNext();" gives me that error: Incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to String .  What am i doing wrong? Really sorry if i can't understand it all.

Comment: No you still do `all = scan.next();` *inside* the loop where you ensure that there is a next token

Comment: @GBlodgett i've tried    while(scan.hasNext()) { 
                                      all = scan.next();
                                 
                                         }   but again , it gives me an error unless i have something in Txt, which i don't have.

Comment: Don't post your code in a comment. It is not readable. Update your question with the code you are executing so we can see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @A.Omag Please [edit] your question to include an [MCVE]. If the only thing you are doing is that loop, it will not throw a NoSuchElementException